# Failed to extract a fund price from website....what have I done wrong?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to extract the daily NAV price for A(Mdis)HKD from the price table in the middle of this website:

http://www.franklintempleton.com.hk/en_HK/investor/funds/price-and-distribution/256/Templeton-Global-Bond-Fund/Pricing-

I used the importXML function in Google Sheets

=importxml(,"//div[@class='pageTitle']/h1")

But it didn't return anything.

I have played with the formula for a long time and couldn't resolve the issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It is okay to have links to external web sites to provide context or auxiliary information but these links *cannot replace* the information which is essential to your question. Here you should show the XML you are trying to import. If the XML is too big, then pare it down to something smaller that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This site seems to build on cookies for verifying you accepted some terms. Open the page in private mode or another browser to see what I'm talking about; Google Spreadsheets will see the same page, too.

As you cannot use Cookies with Google Spreadsheets without programming scripts (and even them I'm not sure), you will not be able to to read this information using `importxml(...)`.